# Android PopupMenu how to change menu item text color?

Tags: android, android-menu, android-popupwindow

I have created style that change the popup menu background color and now i need to know how to change the menu item text color too. Below is the style i am using

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/popup_menu_bg_color</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 7):

Apply this style code to your application/activity theme style

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
```

Comment: It's EXACTLY what I need!

Comment: Follow me http://www.readyandroid.com or check more about popup menu http://www.readyandroid.com/popup-menu-with-icon

Answer (score 0):

Question [android popup menu text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652964/android-popup-menu-text-color-appcompat) might have answer which you need.

If you use TextAppearance.AppCompat.Base.Widget.PopupMenu, you might use TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu instead.

Comment: Is that means i have to change theme? I need to use Holo theme. Anyway, I have resource not found error with
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

Comment: It just means you didn't use support library.

Comment: So maybe this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680728/how-to-change-menu-item-text-color-of-holo-theme-in-android would be useful.

Comment: Check https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/change-menu-item-background-color-and-text-color-android/ for menu text color and for many more https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/